# How to create an observation with 0 in the column

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform

I am using the code below to get the quarterly wages for individuals from 2010Q1-2020Q4. If an individual did not work in a particular quarter they do not have an observation for that quarter. Instead, I would like for there to be an observation but have the quarterly wage be 0. For example,

```
What is currently happening:
|  MPI  | Quarter| Wage|
|PersonA|2010Q1  | 100 |
|PersonA|2010Q2  | 100 |
|PersonA|2010Q3  | 100 | 
|PersonB|2010Q1  | 100 |

Desired output
|  MPI  | Quarter| Wage|
|PersonA|2010Q1  | 100 |
|PersonA|2010Q2  | 100 |
|PersonA|2010Q3  | 100 | 
|PersonA|2010Q4  |  0  |
|PersonB|2010Q1  | 100 |
|PersonB|2010Q2  |  0  |
|PersonB|2010Q3  |  0  | 
|PersonB|2010Q4  |  0  |
```

```
        ws_data AS (
    SELECT
        MASTER_PERSON_INDEX AS mpi
        ,SUBSTR(cast(wg.naics as string), 1, 2) AS NAICS_2
        ,SUBSTR(cast(wg.yrqtr as string), 0,5) AS quarter
        ,wg.yrqtr
        ,wg.employer
        ,wg.wages
        ,SUBSTR(cast(wg.yrqtr as string), 0,4) AS YEAR
    FROM
        (   SELECT
                *
            FROM
                `ws.ws_ui_wage_records_di` wsui
            WHERE  
                wsui.MASTER_PERSON_INDEX IN (SELECT mpi FROM rc_table_ra16_all_grads_1b)
                AND
                wsui.yrqtr IN (20101, 20102, 20103, 20104,
                        20111, 20112, 20113, 20114,
                        20121, 20122, 20123, 20124,
                        20131, 20132, 20133, 20134,
                        20141, 20142, 20143, 20144,
                        20151, 20152, 20153, 20154,
                        20161, 20162, 20163, 20164,
                        20171, 20172, 20173, 20174,
                        20181, 20182, 20183, 20184,
                        20191, 20192, 20193, 20194,
                        20201, 20202, 20203, 20204)
                                             )wg



    ),

    ws_agg AS (
    SELECT
        mpi
--      ,STATS_MODE(NAICS_2) AS NAICS_2 
   --   ,STATS_MODE(NAICS_DESC) AS NAICS_DESC
        ,quarter
        ,SUM(wages) AS wages_quart
    FROM
        ws_data

    GROUP BY
        mpi, quarter
    ),

    ws_annot AS (
    SELECT
        dagg.*
        ,row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY dagg.mpi, cast(wages_quart as string) ORDER BY dagg.wages_quart  DESC)AS rn
    FROM
        ws_agg dagg
    )
```

Comment: Why don't you want rows for PersonB, 2010Q2,3,4?  Do you only want up to the last quarter each person has data for?

Comment: That was an error on my part. I would like to have 0s for those quarters as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this data to create a CTE at the top as a Quarter table and then using that as the starting point in your main from statement. You should be able to replace the original code I copied from (wg where statement) with that top CTE as well.

```
 (20101, 20102, 20103, 20104,
 20111, 20112, 20113, 20114,
 20121, 20122, 20123, 20124,
 20131, 20132, 20133, 20134,
 20141, 20142, 20143, 20144,
 20151, 20152, 20153, 20154,
 20161, 20162, 20163, 20164,
 20171, 20172, 20173, 20174,
 20181, 20182, 20183, 20184,
 20191, 20192, 20193, 20194,
 20201, 20202, 20203, 20204)
```

Your db may have a DateDimension table with quarters in it that you could use as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want all quarters, and all individuals, one way to achieve this is to start with building all individual-quarter combinations in your data and use that as a 'driver' in a left join; like this:

```
select
    Pers.MID
  , Qtr.Quarter
  , coalesce(W.Wage,0) as Wage
  , ...
from 
   (select distinct MPIfrom YourTable) Pers
   cross join
   (select distinct Quarter from DateDimensionTable) Qtr
   left join
   YourTable W
   on w.MPI=Pers.MPI
   and w.Quarter=Qtr.Quarter
```

If your table has all the periods you are interested in, you can use YourTable, instead of DateDimensionTable. But if it doesn't, and I guess it can't be guaranteed, then you can use a Date/Calendar table here , if you have any, or you can dynamically generate quarters between min and max quarter in YourTable; just search for these terms). You can also hardcode them as you have in your query (as JBontje recommended).

If a combination is missing from YourTable then the Wage for that combo will be null, you can use coalesce to treat it as zero.